# Wack-A-Circle Game Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, game-physics, geometry

The Idea is that this game generates circles every 15 millisecond at a random location. It doesn't seem to recognise the variable initialize and doesn't create a new circle or even generate one at all

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="wack-a-circle.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="initialize();">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="848" height="600" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

And now the javascript

```
var canvas;
var circles = [];
var circleRadius = 50;
var score = 0;
var xaxis = getRandom(848)
var yaxis = getRandom(600)

function wackableCircle(){
    xaxis = getRandom(848)
    yaxis = getRandom(600)
    if(circles.length > 10){
        alert("You lose!\nScore: " + score)
    }
    setTimeout(function() {circles.push(new wackableCircle()}, 1000 - (score / 5));
}
function getRandom(max){
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max));
}
function initialize(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown)
    //add new circle every 1000ms
    setTimeout(function () {circles.push(new wackableCircle())}, 1000);
    setInterval(function () {updateCanvas()}, 15); //Update canvas every 15ms.
}
//Find difference between two numbers.
function numberDifference (a, b){
    return Math.abs(a - b);
}
function onMouseDown(event){
    for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
        var wackableCircle = circles[i];
        if(numberDifference(event.clientX, xaxis) < circleRadius){
            //The circle's X and the mouse's X are within 50.
            if(numberDifference(event.clientY, yaxis) < circleRadius){
                //The circle's Y and the mouse's Y are also with in 50.
                circles.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    alert("click at " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY);
}
function updateCanvas(){
    //clear canvas
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, 848, 600);
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
        wackableCircle = circles[i];
        //Draw circle at wackableCircle's x and y.
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.arc(xaxis, yaxis, circleRadius, 0 ,Math.PI * 2);
        canvasContext.fill();
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, you need to fix your syntax errors, before you move forward. Your `setTimeout` callback function is missing a closing `)` (parenthesis) at the end of your `push()` call as well as at the end of the call itself. Also, you should use the `width` and `height` of the canvas rather than using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29%23Magic_numbers_in_other_uses).

Answer (score 1):

I can get you a step further fairly easier, which I think answers your question about getting something to display. It doesn't make the whole thing work though.

Update

```
setTimeout(function() {circles.push(new wackableCircle()}, 1000 - (score / 5));
```

With

```
setTimeout(function() { circles.push(new wackableCircle()) }, 1000 - (score / 5));
```

You were missing a closing bracket after new wackableCircle().

---

Another step closer..

```
var canvas;
var circles = [];
var circleRadius = 50;
var score = 0;
var xaxis = getRandom(848)
var yaxis = getRandom(600)

function wackableCircle(){
    return { x: getRandom(848), y : getRandom(600)};
}

function getRandom(max){
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max));
}
function initialize(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown)
    //add new circle every 1000ms
    setInterval(function () {circles.push(new wackableCircle())}, 1000 - (score / 5));
    setInterval(function () {updateCanvas()}, 15); //Update canvas every 15ms.
}
//Find difference between two numbers.
function numberDifference (a, b){
    return Math.abs(a - b);
}
function onMouseDown(event){
    for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
        var w = circles[i];
        if(numberDifference(event.clientX, w.x) < circleRadius){
            //The circle's X and the mouse's X are within 50.
            if(numberDifference(event.clientY, w.y) < circleRadius){
                //The circle's Y and the mouse's Y are also with in 50.
                circles.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    alert("click at " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY);
}
function updateCanvas(){
    //clear canvas
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, 848, 600);
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
        w = circles[i];
        //Draw circle at wackableCircle's x and y.
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.arc(w.x, w.y, circleRadius, 0 ,Math.PI * 2);
        canvasContext.fill();
    }
}
```

There was a major flaw in your code where wackableCircle() wasn't actually returning anything. I've now got it returning a simple object with random x & y coords that we can query against. Your version is using variables defined somewhere else in the code and not the random ones for the object you intended to create.
The logic for speeding up the circles appearing probably isn't right here, but you'll get it :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="848" height="600" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="wack-a-circle.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                initialize();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A whole jQuery library just for the ready function? That might be a little overkill..

Comment: True. It is just a suggestion to get up and running quickly. Better than inline functions and styles, though. Since the question is about a game, the app is probably going to have to include standard (perhaps other) libraries anyway.

Comment: The point is, there maybe a problem calling a function from a script that is loaded in the head tag, in the body onload

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of issues,

These include:

- Missing semi-colons `;`
- Missing `)`
- Function name being redeclared as a variable

---

In your `updateCanvas()` function you are doing this:

```
wackableCircle = circles[i];
```

This makes the function called `wackableCircle` undefined, consider making it a local variable with

```
var wackableCircle = circles[i];
```

P.S - I can't see where this is being used anyway?

---

As **Darren Dourley** mentioned, you've got a missing `)` in your timeout function.
Update

```
setTimeout(function() {circles.push(new wackableCircle()}, 1000 - (score / 5));
```

With

```
setTimeout(function() { circles.push(new wackableCircle()) }, 1000 - (score / 5));
```

---

Not a show stopper - but You are missing a lot of `;` If you ever minify your code this will break it.

---

One line functions make errors hard to spot, breaking the functions onto multiple lines (the `setTimeout` function specifically makes it easier to see problems), Here is the fixed code

```
var canvas;
var circles = [];
var circleRadius = 50;
var score = 0;
var xaxis = getRandom(848);
var yaxis = getRandom(600);

function wackableCircle() {
    xaxis = getRandom(848);
    yaxis = getRandom(600);
    if (circles.length > 10) {
        alert("You lose!\nScore: " + score)
    }
    setTimeout(
        function () {
            circles.push(new wackableCircle())
        }, 1000 - (score / 5)
    );
}

function getRandom(max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max));
}

function initialize() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
    //add new circle every 1000ms
    setTimeout(function () {
        circles.push(new wackableCircle())
    }, 1000);
    setInterval(function () {
        updateCanvas()
    }, 15); //Update canvas every 15ms.
}

//Find difference between two numbers.
function numberDifference(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a - b);
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        var wackableCircle = circles[i];
        if (numberDifference(event.clientX, xaxis) < circleRadius) {
            //The circle's X and the mouse's X are within 50.
            if (numberDifference(event.clientY, yaxis) < circleRadius) {
                //The circle's Y and the mouse's Y are also with in 50.
                circles.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    alert("click at " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY);
}

function updateCanvas() {
    //clear canvas
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, 848, 600);
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        var wackableCircle = circles[i];
        //Draw circle at wackableCircle's x and y.
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.arc(xaxis, yaxis, circleRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        canvasContext.fill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Idea is that this game generates circles every 15 millisecond at a random location.

Well, you should not create a new circle each time, just displace it from its previous location.

> It doesn't seem to recognise the variable initialize and doesn't create a new circle or even generate one at all

Your `initialize()` function exists in global scope, so you will have to make sure it is defined before in the head of your document. The `<body onLoad="initialize()">` event should be firing correctly, again, just as long as the script is in the `<head>` of the document. Alternatively, you could define a `ready(fn)` function to listen for when the DOM finishes loading. See below, for more information.

## Let's get started

You need to fix a couple things.

- First off, you need to fix your syntax errors, before you move forward. Your `setTimeout` callback function is missing a closing `)` (parenthesis) at the end of your `push()` call as well as at the end of the call itself.
- You should use the `width` and `height` of the canvas rather than using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29%23Magic_numbers_in_other_uses).
- You need a game state to determine if your game is running. Currently, if you fix your syntax errors, your game will repeatedly spam an alert saying that you have lost.

  ```
  var running = false; // GAME IS STOPPED
  ```
- You need to wait until the document has finished loading before grabbing elements. [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready) has some sample code for adding jQuery-like functionality to your codebase without having to include the entire library.

  ```
  ready(initialize); // Wait for DOM to be ready.

  function ready(fn) {
      if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
          fn();
      } else {
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
      }
  }
  ```
- Also, if you want to display the entire circle inside the canvas your range should start at half the circle's radius to the width if the canvas minus the radius.

  ```
  function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

  var xaxis = getRandom(circleRadius, width - circleRadius);
  ```

If you are using JavaScript OOP techniques with the `new` operator, you should remove your global variables for radius, and x/y axis and define them locally on your circle. Either do that or do not create a constructor, because you are mixing OOP and functional paradigms.

The `alert()` function does not work in this code snippet below, but you can check out the example [via JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67ymaggy/12/).

---

## Working Demo

```js
var canvas;
var circles = [];
var circleRadius = 50;
var score = 0;

var width = 848; // Width of canvas.
var height = 600; // Height of canvas.

var running = false; // GAME IS STOPPED
var updateRate = 15; // Redraw the canvas every 15ms.
var movementRate = 1000; // Draw circle every second.
var maxMoves = 10; // Max number of displacements.

var xaxis = getRandom(width);
var yaxis = getRandom(height);

ready(initialize); // Wait for DOM to be ready.

// http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready
function ready(fn) {
    if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
        fn();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
}

function WackableCircle() {
    xaxis = getRandom(width);
    yaxis = getRandom(height);
    if (circles.length > maxMoves) {
        alert("You lose!\nScore: " + score);
        running = false; // GAME STOPPED
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            circles.push(new WackableCircle());
        }, movementRate - (score / 5));
    }
}

function getRandom(max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max));
}

function initialize() {
    running = true; // GAME IS RUNNING

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown)
    //add new circle every 1000ms
    setTimeout(function () {
        circles.push(new WackableCircle())
    }, movementRate);
    setInterval(function () {
        updateCanvas()
    }, updateRate); //Update canvas every 15ms.
}
// Find difference between two numbers.
function numberDifference(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a - b);
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        var wackableCircle = circles[i];
        if (numberDifference(event.clientX, xaxis) < circleRadius) {
            //The circle's X and the mouse's X are within 50.
            if (numberDifference(event.clientY, yaxis) < circleRadius) {
                //The circle's Y and the mouse's Y are also with in 50.
                circles.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    alert("click at " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY);
}

function updateCanvas() {
    //clear canvas
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        wackableCircle = circles[i];
        //Draw circle at wackableCircle's x and y.
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.arc(xaxis, yaxis, circleRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        canvasContext.fill();
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="848" height="600" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

---

## Complete; OOP Example

The example below creates a single circle and this circle gets displaced every second. A status bar is drawn at the bottom of the canvas for debugging purposes.

To see a running example of the code below, see the [following demo](http://jsfiddle.net/67ymaggy/16/).

```
var canvas;
var circle = null;
var circleRadius = 50;
var score = 0;

var width = 848; // Width of canvas.
var height = 600; // Height of canvas.

var running = false; // GAME IS STOPPED
var updateRate = 15; // Redraw the canvas every 15ms.
var movementRate = 1000; // Draw circle every second.
var moveCount = 0;
var maxMoves = 10; // Max number of displacements.

var basePoints = 10;
var lastClick = { x: -1, y: -1 };
var hit = false;
var statusText = '';

function WackableCircle(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;

    this.move = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };
    this.displace = function() {
        this.move(
            randomInt(this.radius, width - this.radius),
            randomInt(this.radius, height - this.radius));
    };

    this.displace();
}

function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function initialize() {
    running = true; // GAME IS RUNNING
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown)

    circle = new WackableCircle(circleRadius);

    width = canvas.width; // Override width.
    height = canvas.height; // Override height.

    setTimeout(function () {
        update();
    }, movementRate);

    setInterval(function () {
        redraw();
    }, updateRate);
}

function update() {
    circle.displace();

    if (moveCount >= maxMoves - 1) {
        alert("You lose!\nScore: " + score);
        running = false; // GAME STOPPED
    } else {
        moveCount++;

        setTimeout(function () {
            update();
        }, movementRate - (score / 5));
    }
}

// Find difference between two numbers.
function delta(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a - b);
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
    if (delta(event.clientX, circle.x) < circle.radius) {
        //The circle's X and the mouse's X are within 50.
        if (delta(event.clientY, circle.y) < circle.radius) {
            score += basePoints;
            moveCount--;
            hit = true;
        }
    } else {
        hit = false;
    }

    lastClick = {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY
    };
}

function redraw() {
    statusText = [
        "Score: " + score,
        "Moves: " + (moveCount + 1) + "/" + maxMoves,
        "FPS: " + (1000 / 15).toFixed(2),
        "Last click: (" + lastClick.x + ", " + lastClick.y + ")",
        "Hit: " + (hit ? 'yes' : 'no'),
        "Running: " + (running ? 'yes' : 'no')
    ].join("  |  ");

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.font = 'normal 10pt monospace';
    ctx.fillText(statusText, 12, height - 12);
}
```